# PHP printf not printing, simplexml_load_string not parsing

Tags: php, simplexml, printf

I have some data that won't printf....

echo works, but not printf

There is data in the string, also simplexml_load_string won't parse the string.

There is some binary or invisible character that I cannot see and can't get the ordinal value for that is causing printf to fail as well as most other string functions in PHP.

Clearly this is an encoding issue, however, I don't know how to find out what it is so I can properly encode/decode it.

```
$string = getStringFromDatabase();
printf($string);
```

...

```
Nothing is displayed
```

...

```
No errors, No Warnings, No Nothing
```

Clearly there is data there, I know it's there if I loop over every single character, however, I don't where to go from there.

[UPDATE]
This is weird because the ordinal value is outside of the typical ASCII range.

ord($buffer[$i]) = 1610

it is a combo of a DLE and LF characters.  Not sure how it got there or why.  Or what it was supposed to be, the data on either side is valid and the location for this is quite odd.

think  <offending char here>0,000

Comment: It may be helpful if you can show a short example of the string that won't print.

Comment: Not really a question merely stating something doesn't work. If you want help i think 98% of us want to see code :)

Comment: I came with different numbers: 99.87%

Comment: Hold on let me tap into my psychic ability to figure out exactly what it is you're asking... oh wait

Comment: I got a different number but couldn't print it :(

Comment: Have you tried printf('%s', $string); (as some ppl mentioned in the answers) else you might get wierd effects of the printf function.. (e.g if you have a % sign in your string, it will fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a multi-byte character that is an bug from the runtime.  You can work around it by finding chr(16) in your string and replacing it with  an empty string ("").  That is if you need it to work with s/v/printf functions.

Answer (score 5):

Definition of printf:

```
int printf  ( string $format  [, mixed $args  [, mixed $...  ]] )
```

Isn't your problem simply that you are passing your string as $format? Don't you need to use simply `print` or provide `printf` with a `$format` string AND a `$string`?

Answer (score 2):

[echo](http://php.net/echo) will output a string literally, but if you pass your string as the first parameter to [printf](http://php.net/printf), it is interpreted as format - if it contains % characters, these may be the source of your problem.

If this works:

```
echo $foo
```

then so should this:

```
printf("%s", $foo);
```

If you want to get a quick and dirty hex dump of a string, try something like

```
$foo="fo \00 33jj";

$len=strlen($foo);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
{
  printf("%02x ", ord($foo[$i]));
}

//outputs 66 6f 20 00 20 33 33 6a 6a
```

Comment: If I could print out the data, then I wouldn't be asking this!  lol

Actually, it's medical data and so it's secret.  If I could find the offending character, then I could fix it.

This is why I'm asking...freaking stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Look at here: http://ditio.net/2008/11/04/php-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string-functions/ and perhaps just display the hex representation, and the bad characters may come out, but; you can also just go through the string and copy all the printable characters (ASCII > 31 and < 128) into a new string and then print out that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file_put_contents('tmp.txt', $string);
```

then load it in a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

At that point I would try as the string could be empty:

```
echo "'" . $string . "'<br>";
```